# permitAll в Spring boot не работает

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

писал я аутентификацию для мульти-модульного проекта с MongoDb, но почему-то когда я пытаюсь отправить какой-либо запрос на какой-либо контроллер то мне возвращает 401 код причём без тела запроса. Помогите как решить эту проблему.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncodeer() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncodeer());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите дать всем доступ, зачем jwttokenfilter?) либо удалите фильтр, либо назначьте эндпоинты к которым нужен определенный доступ. 401 значит unauthorized. Наверняка тогда ошибка в фильтре, смотрите чтобы не выбрасывало ошибку если токен отсутствует, или проверьте что в шапке у него префикс Bearer